# Cannot Switch between Bootstrap Tabs

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I need to switch between Bootstrap tabs on a button click in each tab .However Its not working .I have been trying various ways but couldn't find any help.Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

```
<div class="col-md-6"  style="width:100%;margin-top:20px">
    <div class="tab" id="tabs1" role="tabpanel">
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="TabList" role="tablist">
             <li id="result1" role="presentation"  runat="server"><a href="#Section7" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Registration</a></li>
             <li id="result2" role="presentation"   runat="server" ><a href="#Section8"  aria-controls="home" role="tab"  data-toggle="tab">Financially Personal Details</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"  ><a href="#Section9" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Confirmation</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- Tab panes -->
         <div class="tab-content tabs">
            <!--  Information -->
             <div  role="tabpanel" runat="server" id="Section7">
            <table  width="100%" align="center" >
<tr><td colspan="4">
<table width="100%">
<tr><td ><label  > Name  </label><asp:TextBox  ID="txt_Name"  runat="server" 
 Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
    </td><td align="left"><label  >Contact Number </label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Cnumber" TabIndex="8" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
   <tr>
 <td><asp:Button ID="but_Submit" runat="server" Text="Register" 
   OnClick="but_Submit_Click" TabIndex="23"></asp:Button>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <!--End  Information -->
    <!-- Financially  Party -->
    <div role="tabpanel" runat="server" id="Section8">
    <table  width="100%" align="center" >
    <tr><td colspan="4">
    <table width="100%"  class="w3-card w3-table w3-small">
    <tr><td ><label  >Bearer Name</label>
    <asp:TextBox  ID="txt_fbname"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </td><td align="left"><label  >Relation to Patient  </label>
    <asp:TextBox  ID="txt_rtp" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><asp:Button ID="Button6" runat="server" Text="SAVE" 
     OnClick="but_Submit1_Click" TabIndex="23"></asp:Button>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
  <!--End Financially Responsible Party -->
  <!--Emergency Contact -->
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="Section9">
  <table width="100%"  class="w3-card w3-table w3-small">
  <tr><td ><label  >Contact Name  </label><asp:TextBox ID="txt_emname"  
   runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
  </td><td align="left"><label  >Relation to Patient  </label>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txt_emrtp" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td><asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" Text="SAVE" 
  OnClick="but_Submit2_Click" TabIndex="23"></asp:Button>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
                   </div>
             <!--End Emergency Contact -->
    This is my code behind :
    Page load :
                    result1.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
                    Section7.Attributes.Add("class", "tab-pane active");
                    //hide the employment tab (menu and content)
                    Section8.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    Section8.Attributes.Add("class", "tab-pane");
                    result2.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    result2.Attributes.Add("class", "nav nav-tabs");
Buttton_Click Event:
            result2.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
             Section8.Attributes.Add("class", "tab-pane active");
            //hide the personal tab (menu and content)
            Section7.Attributes.Remove("class");
            Section7.Attributes.Add("class", "tab-pane");
            result1.Attributes.Remove("class");
            result1.Attributes.Add("class", "nav nav-tabs");
```

This is my code.It is working fine .But after button click it doesn't switch to the next tab.

Comment: The markup code you supplied is either partial or missing lots of tags. I doesn't mean to say that's is the issue. just mentioned

Comment: There are 2 submit events but you provided only one. What does debugging through submit handlers result in. Check the attributes on each pane. Also the page load code is inside or outside the postback condition ?

Comment: @NitinSingh: ideally the question doesn't contains necessary information right?>

Comment: @NitinSingh is probably correct that the page load code is executing on postback, which is resetting the tabs to their default state. If you add `if(Page.IsPostBack) return;` to the top of your page load method I wouldn't be surprised if it worked.

Comment: @NitinSingh The load code is inside postback condition.

Comment: Ideally pageLoad should be empty entirely. Any default styles should be added to markup and then any changes done via event handlers. If you can use jQuery, try to set the styles client side to avoid posting and reconstructing everything.

Comment: @NitinSingh Could you be more specific since I am new to c#

Comment: The reason why its not working is due to missing table and div element closing. If you try to format the markup, each valid section will be collapsible, and any missing tags will be indicated. Please update the markup and then try

Comment: @NitinSingh It is working now.The problem was that I have given the submit form in a an updatepanel to avoid post back .When I removed it , It is switching to next tab ,but the page is postback and goes to another div section in the same page . Is there any possible way to retain in the same div section and switch to next tab in that div section.

Comment: Please post a fresh question, showing the whole code. UpdatePanel and postback are opposite, seem something mis-configured